# Calculating weighted average with criteria SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the below structure:

```
      model term transaction str_weight
      750i    36    L        2
      750i    39    L        3
      750i    48    D        3
      750i    39    L        3
      750i    48    L        3
```

I need to calculate the weighted average by transaction in SQL and display it in the below format:

```
     model L_Term   D_Term D_L_Term 
     750i    48      36     48            (not accurate values)
```

This is what I tried so far and it is giving me incorrect results.
Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Any better way of doing these weighed averages in sql?

```
select model
 , sum(str_weight) as TotalWeight           
 , sum(case when [transaction] = 'D' then Term*str_weight end)/sum(case when [transaction] = 'D' then str_weight else 0.0 end) as Weighted_D_Term
 , sum(case when [transaction] = 'L' then Term*str_weight end)/sum(case when [transaction] = 'L' then str_weight else 0.0 end) as Weighted_L_Term
 , sum(case when [transaction] = 'D' OR [transaction] = 'L' then Term*str_weight end)/sum(case when [transaction] = 'D' OR [transaction] = 'L' then str_weight else 0.0 end) Weighted_DL_Term
from model_weights
group by model
```

Thanks,
B

Comment: Your query has syntax error. the result your provided, is not correct. I edited your question. Also please provide the desired result set so we can provide an answer.

Comment: Your logic looks correct to me.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for responding. Apologies for the dumb question, How do I setup a SQL Fiddle here?

Comment: @JamesL. thanks for responding. Yes, in the actual implementation, I did handle the divide by zeros  and nulls etc.

Comment: @Flicker thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I missed the end in the post here. The desired result set is in the second box. im trying to compute the weighted average by transaction

Comment: @Bee, Your query (after fix), returns the same result, so why you think that is not right result?

Comment: @Bee . . . Go to www.sqlfiddle.com.  You set up the tables and insert the data on the left.  You can run queries on the right.  When done, you can place a link to the page in the question.  Voila!  Everyone has access to the test environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example.  It's really no different than what you've provided in your question except it includes details that are just inferred in your question.

Given the formula: **sum(term * weight) / sum(weight)**

The following query:

```
create table #temp (model varchar(10), term int, [transaction] char(1), str_weight float)

insert into #temp values
('750i', 36, 'L', 2),
('750i', 39, 'L', 3),
('750i', 48, 'D', 3),
('750i', 39, 'L', 3),
('750i', 48, 'L', 3)

select model
      ,sum(str_weight) as TotalWeight
      ,isnull(sum(case when [transaction] = 'D' then term * str_weight end) / sum(case when [transaction] = 'D' then str_weight end), 0.00) as Weighted_D_Term
      ,isnull(sum(case when [transaction] = 'L' then term * str_weight end) / sum(case when [transaction] = 'L' then str_weight end), 0.00) as Weighted_L_Term
      ,isnull(sum(case when [transaction] in ('D', 'L') then term * str_weight end) / sum(case when [transaction] in ('D', 'L') then str_weight end), 0.00) as Weighted_D_L_Term
from   #temp
group by model

drop table #temp
```

Yields this dataset:

```
model      TotalWeight   Weighted_D_Term   Weighted_L_Term   Weighted_D_L_Term
---------- ------------- ----------------- ----------------- -------------------
750i       14            48                40.9090909090909  42.4285714285714
```

Is this inaccurate?  If so, what did you expect differently?  If this isn't what you are getting, then there is something else in the part of the SQL you did not provide in your question that is altering the output.

Comment: Simply remove all the `else` parts and you don't have to care about "division by zero". Btw, this is exactly the same as the original query...

Comment: @dnoeth - Good suggestion, and I know it is exactly the same, which is why I said it's *no different*.  However, the output of this query is quite a bit different from the OP's sample data.  So, the query in the question didn't create the dataset.  Which implies they omitted the errant SQL.  Perhaps it would have been better to just edit the OP's question and to include the `#temp` table code.  But that would have changed their question, which I don't think we should do...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. Yes, it turns out what I am doing is indeed correct. The dataset has missing values which were throwing the weighted averages off. Once I imputed those, I was able to arrive at the right answer. Felt silly for missing that important piece when calculating.